# Will longer DB transactions make calls to other DB wait?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction, timeout

I have a fundamental question but unable to find precise information online.

I opened up a DB transaction (SQL Server) and making multiple inserts, updates, delete etc; the entire process takes about 5 hours to complete (Due to the volume of Data; Assume this is valid).

Now my question is,

All the above happens within the scope of a transaction.  Will this longer transaction make calls to other DB on the same server wait OR disturb them in anyway? My understanding is, this will impact only the calls made to the concerned DB and NOT other databases under the same instance.

Comments / responses and greatly appreciated.

Comment: the answer is, it depends. If both DB'S are on the same physical disk, for sure you will have a delay in case you touch the disk in your transaction. Also the other transactions of course may wait for the cpu. One idea is to check the actual waits. If you have workload groups for cpu and filegroups in place you can limit the "disturbing".

Comment: This will have no transactional effect on any of the other databases, assuming the DML you are doing doesn't cross database containers to those other databases (i.e. distributed transactions). You will, however, cause massive blocking and poor transaction log management by using a single long huge transaction - I would cut this up into phases and multiple smaller more manageable bunches of transactions.